# parsing unusual Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Java to download some information. I am receiving a JSON with the following format:

> [[40217657,1498658666000,-0.08537438,2498.9],(...)]

My problem is that I don't know how to build the wrapper class since this JSON has no keywords.

Here is the wrapper class I am trying to use:

```
package TaskFormats;

public class TaskBitFinexTrades {
    private double[] info;
    public TaskBitFinexTrades(double[] info) {
        super();
        this.info = info;
    }
    public double[] getInfo() {return info;}
    public void setInfo(double[] info) {this.info = info;}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[TimeStamp:" + info[1] + ",Id:" + info[0] + ",amount:" + info[2] + ",price:" + info[3] ;
    }

}
```

And here is how I am trying to use Gson

```
public void loadBitFinexTrades(){
    String url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/trades/tBTCUSD/hist/?limit=1000";
    String json="";
    try{
        json = conecction(url);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    if(json!=""){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<TaskBitFinexTrades>>() {}.getType();
        List<TaskBitFinexTrades> fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        for (TaskBitFinexTrades task : fromJson) {
            System.out.println(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you do know that what you got there is not, in fact valid JSON?

Comment: *"since this Json has no keywords"* There are only 3 keywords in JSON: `true`, `false`, and `null`. Most JSON texts uses none of them, so what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Vogel612 I think we can assume that `.....` is not literal, and simply means that actual JSON text has a lot more subarrays, that was shortened for our benefit, in which case it is perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: @Andreas hum ... interesting. I seem to misremember constraints on the top-level item in JSON :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is JSON array of arrays, not an object. Instead of trying to read your object from JSON, read `double[][]` and rebuild your object manually.

*Code below was written ad-hoc, to show my point, haven't tried it, may need some tweaking*

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
double[][] infos = gson.fromJson(json, double[][].class);
List<TaskBitFinexTrades> result = Lists.newArrayList(); //see: guava
for (double[] info: infos)
    result.add(new TaskBitFinexTrades(info));
for (TaskBitFinexTrades task : result) {
    System.out.println(task);
}
```